# Method 'AlertUser' in 'MainActivity' has incorrect signature

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing a simple widget that has a button that when clicked an AlertDialog will pop up displaying a keycode that changes every hour. Currently I have just set it to display "Test".

If I run the app and click the widget's button, a menu pops up saying "One UI Home keeps stopping" and then gives me options to send feedback to android and close the app.
I assume the cause of this is in my widget's XML file, as when I hover over "AlertUser" in the `onClick` attribute, I get a message saying 'Method 'AlertUser' in 'MainActivity' has incorrect signature'. I googled this however none of the solutions for others that I found seem to work.

**Widgets XML File:**

```
      <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:onClick="AlertUser"
          android:text="@string/button1" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
       public void AlertUser(Context context) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Keycode")
            .setMessage("Test")
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .show();
       }
```

No idea what I am doing wrong here, any help appreciated!

Comment: because it is not `View.OnClickListener`?

Comment: Tried that, didn't fix it.

Comment: Have you tried setting click listener with `setOnClickListener` rather than XML?And is proguard enabled when compiling code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `View` in method signature and use `getApplicationContext()` for `AlertDialog`.

```
public void AlertUser(View view) {
   ...
}
```